# Implement react navigation to an existing animated tabbar

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a custom animated tabbar component with react-native-reanimated. Im trying to implement it with react navigation but when i do the animation doesnt work. Any help to what to add for it to be functional.
Here are the components
Tab component

```
interface TabProps {
  children: ReactElement;
  onPress: () => void;
  // navigation: NavigationStackScreenProps<any, any>;
  active: Animated.Node<number>;
  transition: Animated.Node<number>;
  index: number;
  label: string;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
});

export default ({
  children,
  active,
  transition,
  index,
  onPress,
}: TabProps) => {
  const isActive = eq(active, index);

  const activeTransition = withTransition(isActive, {duration: DURATION});
  const isGoingLeft = greaterThan(transition, active);
  const width = interpolateNode(activeTransition, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, ICON_SIZE],
  });
  const direction = cond(
    isActive,
    cond(isGoingLeft, 'rtl', 'ltr'),
    cond(isGoingLeft, 'ltr', 'rtl'),
  );

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...{onPress}}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width: ICON_SIZE,
          height: ICON_SIZE,
          direction
        }}>
        <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>{children}</View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.icon, {width}]}>
          {cloneElement(children, {active: true})}
        </Animated.View>
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
```

TabBar index:

```
const tabs = [
  {icon: <Home />, label: 'Home'},
  {icon: <User />, label: 'Video'},
  {icon: <Tv />, label: 'LiveStream'},
  {icon: <Wallet />, label: 'Signin'},
];
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F0F0F6',
    width: '90%',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    left: '5%',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  tabs: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  tab: {
    width: SEGMENT / 1.2,
    height: ICON_SIZE + PADDING * 2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default ({...props}) => {
  const active = new Value<number>(0);
  let navigation = useNavigation();
  const transition = withTransition(active, {duration: DURATION});
  const activeTransition = new Value(0);
  useCode(
    () =>
      block([
        onChange(active, set(activeTransition, 0)),
        set(activeTransition, timing({duration: DURATION})),
      ]),
    [active, activeTransition],
  );
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.tabs}>
        {tabs.map(({icon, label}, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={styles.tab}>
            <Weave {...{active, transition, index}} />
            <Tab
              onPress={() => {
                active.setValue(index);
                console.log(active);
                // title.setValue(label);
                props.navigation.navigate(label);
              }}
              {...{active, transition, index, label}}>
              {icon}
            </Tab>
          </View>
        ))}
        <Particules {...{transition, activeTransition}} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Here is the dribble example i was trying to copy https://dribbble.com/shots/5380015-WeChat-Tab-Bar-Redesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of `react-native-reanimated` and `react-native` are you using?
There's a few things that I'm seeing that should be causing issues, but I'm also not entirely sure what's available for your versions.

The biggest thing I'm seeing is that you're instantiating new `Value` objects on every render of the component, which should be causing issues if trying to animate in a functional way. Looking into `react-native-reanimated` a little bit there appears to be a few hooks ([`useValue`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/value/) and [`useSharedValue`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/next/api/hooks/useSharedValue/)) that should provide you with a consistent object that you can use where applicable. It looks like you'll want to use `useValue`.

Since the animations are giving you troubles it may be a good idea to use [the examples](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/animations) provided in their fundamentals as good reference for side-by-side comparison. This could be especially useful if you had/have it working as a class component to compare the differences. As well as their [`useAnimatedStyle`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.3.x/api/hooks/useAnimatedStyle/) hook for how they handle animating in a functional component.

A few other items to note

1. You may need to replace the `timing` call to be [`withTiming`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.0.x/api/withTiming/). [`timing`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/animations/timing/) appears to be specific for v1
2. Rather than using `set` you may want to `useSharedValue` and just assign to the shared value's `value` property. [`set`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/nodes/set/) also appears to be specifically for v1 of reanimated

```
// useSharedValue is provided by "react-native-reanimated"
const active = useSharedValue(0);
const activeTransition = useSharedValue(0);

// useEffect is provided by "react"
useEffect(() => {
  // Set activeTransition to 0
  activeTransition.value = 0;
}, [active.value]); // When active.value changes
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Also, as a side comment, if you're not familiar with hooks in react, it may be a good idea to look through the [react documentation relating to them](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), or even just [their API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for the information provided, i figured it out a couple of days ago about the useValue and stuff. Im working with the latest version of react native and reanimated 2. I will accept this as a valid answer and give you the bounty. Thanks once again and cheers